# Calculate and plot segmentation mask pixels

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-segmentation

I have the following image:

[image]

Below is a segmentation mask within this image:

[image: Segmentation mask]

From the image above, I attempted to calculate the non-zero pixel coordinates. That is, I tried to get all of the pixels of the actual clouds that are in the mask above. When I plot these non-zero pixels, the results are this:

[image: Plot segmentation mask pixels]

My question is: why are the plotted pixels in the image above not the same as from the segmentation mask, and how do I fix this? I want to get the pixels of the clouds from the segmentation mask.

Code:

```py
# create matrix
canvas = np.zeros((img_h, img_w))

# read in image, convert to grayscale, and create mask
im_color = cv2.imread(first_row.path.values[0], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, mask = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh=110, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# bounding box coordinates for segmentation mask
ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax = 2, 222, 42, 521

# assign mask to coordinates on canvas
canvas[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax] = mask[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax]
y_coords, x_coords = np.where(canvas == 255.0)

# get pixel coordinates of nonzero pixels
pts = np.array(list(zip(x_coords, y_coords)))

# plot original image 
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax1.set_title('Original image')
plt.imshow(im_color)

# plot segmentation mask on canvas
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax2.set_title('Segmentation mask on canvas')
plt.imshow(canvas)

# plot segmentation mask pixels
fig3 = plt.figure()
ax3 = fig3.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax3.set_title('Segmentation mask pixel coordinates')
plt.imshow(im_color, interpolation='none')
poly = patches.Polygon(pts)
ax3.add_patch(poly)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add upon @nathancy's answer and explicitly answer the question: the pixels calculated from the segmentation mask **are** indeed accurate. The reason for the jagged shape in the last plot above is because every coordinate from the mask is plotted as a single (closed) polygon, and all of these points are connected. That is the definition of a polygon:

- "A number of coplanar line segments, each connected end to end to form a closed shape." [source](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygon.html)

So the final plot represents a closed polygon containing every pixel/coordinate from the original segmentation mask.

To produce an accurate polygonal shape, you would need to find the vertices of (any possible) contours from the mask. Example:

```py
# set up canvas for mask
mask = np.zeros((img_h, img_w), dtype=np.uint8)

# assign specific region to mask
mask[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax] = 1

# read in image
im_color = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# convert image to grayscale
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create threshold of image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh=100, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# create segmentation mask of thresholded image
masked_gray = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, thresh, mask = mask)

# calculate contours of segmentation mask
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(masked_gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# get largest contour
tc = max(contours, key=len)

# plot contours
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_title('Segmentation mask')
plt.imshow(masked_gray, interpolation='none')
poly = patches.Polygon(tc[:,0])
ax.add_patch(poly)
plt.show()
```

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html#matplotlib-pyplot-scatter)

[image]

Seems to match the thresholded image

[image]

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

x, y = np.where(thresh > 0)
plt.scatter(y[::-1], x)
plt.title('Plot segmentation mask pixels')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm really struggling with this. I just don't understand why the pixels that I've calculated do not represent the mask accurately, at least when plotted. I tried creating a full mask too:

```python
# method 1
mask = np.zeros((img_h, img_w), dtype=np.uint8)
mask[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax] = 1

x_m, y_m = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]
x, y = np.vstack([x_m.ravel(), y_m.ravel()])
pts = np.column_stack([x, y])
```

It is still inverted/skewed when plotted.

Comment: @eb18963 The pixel coordinates represent the mask accurately, but if you plot them as a polygon you get lines between consecutive points, which is probably not what you want.