# Inverted pixel coordinates of segmentation mask

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-segmentation

The following is an image of a segmentation mask (it appears yellow). Overlaid onto this mask are the pixels/coordinates of the very same segmentation mask (appears blue).

[image: Segmentation mask]

My question is: why are these pixels/coordinates inverted, transparent and split at the diagonal? Why are they not plotted as a complete "fill", such as the mask itself?

My goal is for these coordinates to appear in "normal" (x,y) linear order. Code:

```py
from matplotlib import patches
import numpy as np

# create mask
mask = np.zeros((350, 525), dtype=np.uint8)

# populate region of mask
mask[2:222,42:521] = 1

# get coordinates of populated region
y, x = np.where(mask == 1)
pts = np.column_stack([x, y])

# define figure, axes, title
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_title('Segmentation mask pixel coordinates')

# show mask
plt.imshow(mask, interpolation='none')

# add mask points
poly = patches.Polygon(pts)
ax.add_patch(poly)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate and plot segmentation mask pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915388/calculate-and-plot-segmentation-mask-pixels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `len(pts)` gives `105380` because `pts` contains all the points of the mask in row-based order. So `poly` has a snake-like shape with length=105380 and width=1. The snake starts in the upper left corner and ends in the lower right - that's why you have diagonal line.

To correct the plot you may do the following modification:

```
# borders
(x1, y1), (x2, y2) = pts.min(axis=0), pts.max(axis=0)
# corners
pts_for_poly = list(zip((x1, x2, x2, x1), (y1, y1, y2, y2)))
# rectangle polygon
poly = patches.Polygon(pts_for_poly)
```

I hope now it looks kinda like expected or close to that.